# Issue Crawling Amazon, Element Cannot Be Scrolled into View

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm having an issue crawling pages on Amazon.

I've tried using:

- Executing JS Script
- Action Chains
- Explicit Waits

Nothing seems to work. Everything throws one exception or error or another.

## Base Script

```
ff = create_webdriver_instance()
ff.get('https://www.amazon.ca/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-3_4bc8_dct_10-?gb_f_c2xvdC0z=sortOrder:BY_SCORE,discountRanges:10-25%252C25-50%252C50-70%252C70-&pf_rd_p=f5836aee-0969-4c39-9720-4f0cacf64bc8&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_r=CQ7KBNXT36G95190QJB1&ie=UTF8')
next_button = ff.find_element_by_xpath('(//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[1]')
```

## Attempt #1: Executing JS

*Script*

```
ff.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', next_button)
```

*Error*

`Element could not be scrolled into view`

## Attempt #2: Action Chain

*Script*

```
actions = ActionChains(ff)
actions.move_to_element(next_button)
actions.click(next_button)
actions.perform()
```

*Error*

`TypeError: rect is undefined`

## Attempt #3: Explicit Wait

```
next_button = WebDriverWait(ff, 60).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[1]'))
)
```

I've also tried using `element_to_be_clickable`. Both of these end up timing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to handle hidden link. Try below instead

```
next_button = ff.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Next')
next_button.click()
```

or

```
next _button = ff.find_element_by_link_text('Next→')
```

Note that `find_element_by_partial_link_text`/`find_element_by_link_text` searching for *visible* links only.

Also you might need to call

```
ff.implicitly_wait(10)
```

once in your script (somewhere after your WebDriver instance definition) or use ExplicitWait as below

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

next_button = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next→')))
```

to be sure that required element will be find even with rendering delay

Comment: But the button is visible in DOM and not hidden?!?! so why didnt my methods work?

Comment: No. The button found by `//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[1]` is located inside `div` with class name `hidden`. Note that index `[1]` in XPath means *first*. If you want to handle *second* (*visible*) link, you should use `//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[2]`. But as I've said search by link text is more reliable way as it will ignore all hidden links...

Comment: youre wrong, only `[2]` has a parent with `hidden`, so how come `(//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[1]` doesn't work??

Comment: `(//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[1]` has no problem finding the link, but for some reason it cannot scroll it into view...

Comment: Have no idea why you still disagree. First link is obviously hidden, second one - visible. If you don't believe me, try `print(dr.find_element_by_xpath('(//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[1]').is_displayed())` and `print(dr.find_element_by_xpath('(//li/a[contains(text(), "Next")])[2]').is_displayed())`

Comment: i'm disagreeing because according to the source code of the website it's `[2]` whose parent is `hidden` whereas `[1]` is visible. have you looked at the source code??

Comment: Yeah. I did it couple of times :) First is still hidden

Comment: i just looped thru it. `[1]` is hidden only on the initial page, then it switches for the rest of it. but it keeps failing on page 10 for some reason...

Comment: `[1]
False
[2]
True |
[1]
True
[2]
False |
[1]
True
[2]
False |
[1]
True
[2]
False |
[1]
True
[2]
False |
[1]
True
[2]
False |
[1]
True
[2]
False |
[1]
True
[2]
False |
[1]
True
[2]
False`

Comment: But you need generic solution that should work on *each* page *including initial* where first link is hidden, right?

Comment: Try this also `ff.find_element_by_link_text('Next →')`. I'm not sure about that `→` as it's not an ASCII char. But search by full link text should avoid matching links that contains "Next" substring

Comment: ok. for some reason it keeps failing on page 10... i cant seem to figure out why this is happening

Comment: Yeah, it should be exact character as it appears on page. It might be incorrectly interpreted when copying from comment...

Comment: ive tried it doesnt work. why does the script keep breaking on page 10?

Comment: Which code line? What is the Exception? Also try to copy `Next →` directly from page into your Python GUI (e.g. Pycharm)

Comment: `NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: Next` from `ff.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Next')`. ill have to try the PyCharm thing tomo, im just going to bed

Comment: Try to call `ff.implicitly_wait(10)` once in the top of script and then `ff.find_element_by_link_text('Next→').click()`. Works fine for me on all the pages

Comment: fuck i cant believe it. i removed my implicit wait just for testing and of course it turns out to be that... lol